# How to run nextjs in AWS lambda with `experimental-edge` runtime

Tags: aws-lambda, next.js, vercel

I'm trying to find a way to run Next.js (v13.0.6) with OG image generation logic (using [@vercel/og](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/edge-functions/og-image-generation)) in AWS Lambda

Everything works fine locally (in dev and prod mode) but when I try execute lambda handler getting `"statusCode": 500,`
It only fails for apis that involve `ImageResponse` (and `runtime: 'experimental-edge'` as a requirement for `@vercel/og`)

I'm pretty sure the problem is caused by [Edge Runtime](https://edge-runtime.vercel.sh/packages/runtime) is not being configured correctly

There is my handler code

1. `next build` with next.config.js `output: 'standalone'` creates folder `.next/standalone`
2. insde standalone `handler.js`

```js
const { parse } = require('url');
const NextServer = require('next/dist/server/next-server').default
const serverless = require('serverless-http');
const path = require('path');
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'
process.chdir(__dirname)

const currentPort = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000

const nextServer = new NextServer({
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: currentPort,
  dir: path.join(__dirname),
  dev: false,
  customServer: false,
  conf: {...} // copied from `server.js` in there same folder
});


const requestHandler = nextServer.getRequestHandler();

// this is a AWS lambda handler that converts lambda event
// to http request that next server can process
const handler = serverless(async (req, res) => {
  // const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
  try {
    await requestHandler(req, res);
  }catch(err){
    console.error(err);
    res.statusCode = 500
    res.end('internal server error')
  }
});

module.exports = {
  handler
}
```

testing it locally with [local-lambda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-local), but getting similar results when test against AWS deployed lambda

what is confusing is that server.js (in .next/standalone) has a similar setup, it only involves `http` server on top of of it

#### update:

aws lambda logs show
`ERROR  [Error [CompileError]: WebAssembly.compile(): Compiling function #64 failed: invalid value type 'Simd128', enable with --experimental-wasm-simd @+3457 ]`

#### update 2:

the first error was fixed by selecting `Node 16` for AWS lambda, now getting this error

```
{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "write after end",
  "trace": [
    "Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end",
    "    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)",
    "    at ServerlessResponse.end (node:_http_outgoing:846:15)",
    "    at ServerlessResponse.end (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/compression/index.js:22:783)",
    "    at NodeNextResponse.send (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-http/node.js:93:19)",
    "    at NextNodeServer.handleRequest (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:332:47)",
    "    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)",
    "    at async /var/task/index.js:34:5"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment of writing Vercel's `runtime: 'experimental-edge'` seems to be unstable (run into multiple issues with it)

I ended up recreating `@vercel/og` lib without wasm and next.js dependencies, can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/romanlv/4f3c78b661bd530779d488189461032a)

and simply use it in AWS lambda. It depends on `@resvg/resvg-js` instead of wasm version, which uses binaries, so there should not be much perf loss comparing to wasm